# Getting error while installing 'formatter' module

Tags: python

I am trying to install formatter using,

pip install formatter

but it throws the following error,

```
Collecting formatter
  Using cached formatter-1.0.3.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/2b/x_hy0wt13mgcbznrm263kzmr0000gr/T/pip-install-l76arg1s/formatter_b9bbf1e04d7a4bda8f51556e744f0357/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
          import formatter as metadata
        File "/private/var/folders/2b/x_hy0wt13mgcbznrm263kzmr0000gr/T/pip-install-l76arg1s/formatter_b9bbf1e04d7a4bda8f51556e744f0357/formatter/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
          from .formatter import Formatter
        File "/private/var/folders/2b/x_hy0wt13mgcbznrm263kzmr0000gr/T/pip-install-l76arg1s/formatter_b9bbf1e04d7a4bda8f51556e744f0357/formatter/formatter.py", line 4, in <module>
          from cStringIO import StringIO
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried installing cStringIO but it throws another error,

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cStringIO (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cStringIO
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install a package which is meant for `python 2.x` in  `python 3.x`. `cStringIO` has been renamed to `io` in `python 3`. But i would suggest you to look for another package, as the `formatter` package has been last updated 8 years ago, is for `python 2.x` and can be considered abandoned (the github repo doesn't even exist anymore).

Comment: This package seems to be deprecated. Can you try installing [formatter2](https://github.com/WoLpH/python-formatter): `pip install formatter2`

Answer (score 2):

This package was removed from python 3.10 (see latest [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/formatter.html) from 3.9). You should update the code to not use the formatter module.